# SQL character field concatenation (without using CONCAT() or +)

Tags: sql, string, informix, concatenation

I'm trying to concatenate 3 [char(32)] fields:
title1
title2
title3
into one field, but the catch is that I'm using an older version of SQL and it DOES NOT support the CONCAT() subroutine or the + operator

---

for example:
CONCAT(title1, title2, title3)
(title1 + title2 + title3)
DON'T WORK!!!!
Is there another way?

Comment: What database is it? I know you answered your own question, but if this is tagged with the appropriate RDBMS it will be easier for the next guy who has this issue to find your answer ...

Comment: And now you've told us Informix via the tags (and I spotted this Q quite quickly once it was tagged - but missed it when it wasn't), which version of Informix are you using?  I'd suspect it must be OnLine 5.x, or possibly SE 7.2x.  If it anything much else, you are long overdue for an upgrade.

Comment: im not sure which version... dont know where to find that info.. i just started working here 2 months ago and havent had time to care about that... upgrade? i hope so

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Nevermind... I figured it out...

its

(title1 || title2 || title3)

Comment: FWIW, that's the standard SQL syntax for string concatenation.  It's weird that so many brands of database do something different.